# Style not applied when called

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, styles

so Im new to android and this is my problem :
-when I call style to a textview it doesn't change anything ,here is my style.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- App branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#009688</item>
    <!-- Darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00796B</item>
    <!-- Theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#536DFE</item>
</style>

<!-- Style for header text in the order form -->
<style name="HeaderTextStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF5252</item>
</style>
```

and here is how I call the style

```
    <TextView
    android:hint="@string/topping"
    style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
    />
```

I tried to change just the color of the textview using

```
android:textColor="#FF5252"
```

but it did nothing

could someone help me , Ill be so greatful ,
Thanks in advance

Comment: <TextView
    android:text="@string/topping"
    style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
    /> you have set hint text and changing color of text which is not present use text in tag instead of hint or use textColoHint instead of textColor

Comment: thanks man it works ,can you post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting textColor while you havent set text yet, you need to change textColo to textColorHint or change hint to text if you want to use textColor, for hint you use textColorHint and for text you use textColor like this.

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryNero"
            android:hint="some hint"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryWhite" />
```